fo:block-container contents not wrapping around fo:float - why?
I'm stumped why with the following code, the text does not wrap around the float. In AH's output, the float covers the text.
<fo:float float="start">
  <fo:block-container inline-progression-dimension="1in" block-progression-dimension="0.5in" background-color="yellow" border="1px solid black">
    <fo:block>FLOAT</fo:block>
  </fo:block-container>
</fo:float>
<fo:block-container intrusion-displace="line" space-before.conditionality="discard">
  <fo:block>This text should wrap on the right of the FLOAT.</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container intrusion-displace="line" space-before="3pt">
  <fo:block>This text should wrap on the right of the FLOAT.</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container intrusion-displace="line" space-before="3pt">
  <fo:block>This text should wrap on the right of the FLOAT.</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container intrusion-displace="line" space-before="3pt">
  <fo:block>This text should wrap on the right of the FLOAT.</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>

The rendering I get with AH 7.4MR6 (eval) is:

For reference, I tried XEP 4.30.961 eval, and it gave me:

The latter is what I, probably naively, expected, but I am now not sure which one is right, and above all: WHY. I sure must be missing some detail in the XSL-FO spec. Can someone explain or point me to the relevant text, please?
Thank you!
